# kotlin 1.4.30 firebase crashlytics issue

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

After updating to kotlin 1.4.30 from 1.4.21, I found some issue:

Firebase crashlytics is not working. my logcat says

```
 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:122)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:237)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$1.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:154)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:54)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)
 Sending signal. PID: 17336 SIG: 9
```

A roll back to 1.4.21 fixes the issue.

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Post complete stacktrace.

Comment: In my case the root cause was having Pi hole running on my network (ad blocker) which was blocking Crashlytics from sending events, but still i don't know why it crashes when it fails to send the events, this is a bit weird way of handling this.

Comment: @Abah, do you have any updates here? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me on the emulator, but not on the device.

Make sure your network does not have Charles, a proxy or any sort of mechanism that prevents Firebase from sending the crash report.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the kotlin version is up to date?
(build gradle module)

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

or

(build gradle project)

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
```